# Automatically adjust text size in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The numbers are going to the next line, how to adjust them to come in the same line without changing others size?

Run the below script in full screen:

```css
.card-body {
  display: flex;
}

.card-title {
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: 'Yatra One', cursive;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  .card-title {
    font-size: 3vw;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .card-title {
    font-size: 10vw;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}

.col-10 {
  height: 65px;
}

.col-2 {
  height: 65px;
}

.img-fluid {
  height: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yatra+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



<div class="row">

  <div class="shadow-self card col-md-3 ml-4 mt-3 mb-3 mr-4 border-0" style="background-color: #F0E78C">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZyROdEa.png" width="100">
        <h5 class="card-title float-right">9700005243</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <a href="#number_256" class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#number_256">Get Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="shadow-self card col-md-3 ml-4 mt-3 mb-3 mr-4 border-0" style="background-color: #F0E78C">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZyROdEa.png" width="100">
        <h5 class="card-title float-right">9700005243</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <a href="#number_256" class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#number_256">Get Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="shadow-self card col-md-3 ml-4 mt-3 mb-3 mr-4 border-0" style="background-color: #F0E78C">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZyROdEa.png" width="100">
        <h5 class="card-title float-right">9700005218</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <a href="#number_256" class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#number_256">Get Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="shadow-self card col-md-3 ml-4 mt-3 mb-3 mr-4 border-0" style="background-color: #F0E78C">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZyROdEa.png" width="100">
        <h5 class="card-title float-right">9700005218</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <a href="#number_256" class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#number_256">Get Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="shadow-self card col-md-3 ml-4 mt-3 mb-3 mr-4 border-0" style="background-color: #F0E78C">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZyROdEa.png" width="100">
        <h5 class="card-title float-right">9700005218</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <a href="#number_256" class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#number_256">Get Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="shadow-self card col-md-3 ml-4 mt-3 mb-3 mr-4 border-0" style="background-color: #F0E78C">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZyROdEa.png" width="100">
        <h5 class="card-title float-right">1111111111</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
        <a href="#number_256" class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#number_256">Get Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The numbers are going to the next line, how to adjust them to come in the same line without changing others size?

Also how to display numbers in the middle? (same space in top and bottom)

Answer (score 2):

By default Boostrap wrote `word-break: break-all;`   Changed to `word-break: keep-all;`

Read this 
   [word-break w3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.card-title {
  font-size: 3vw;
  word-break: keep-all !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin: auto` to center them and `white-space: nowrap` to prevent them from wrapping to the next line. Also, I'd suggest making font a bit smaller when resizing screen and/or making blocks bigger.

In case you want them to be absolutely centered and you don't care about overlapping the image, give them:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: In case you're wondering why:
`margin: auto` adds margin evenly on every side.
`position: absolute` positions it absolutely to the nearest relative parent, top and left 50% are self explanatory, but they measure from the element's border(beginning) and so `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` says to move element by 50% of its size on the axis X (first -50%) and Y (second).

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` then it's going out of the div! i.imgur.com/KvFJaZ2.png, & in which class should I give: `position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`?

Comment: `card-title` class I believe, I mean the text with numbers you addressed in your question. It is going to go out of the div when you add `white-space: nowrap` basically because there's not enough space for your text when it's not wrapped. That's why you should consider making font smaller or blocks bigger. The solution with `position: absolute` also works since it doesn't care about image which takes its space as well.